# SQL JOIN only when a condition is true

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 3 variables in my SQL stored procedure and want to add a join only if the 3rd variable is not null.

This is how i am trying to do it but it doesn't work. It gives the following error on the line pointed out:

> Incorrect syntax near '{'

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search] 
@one NVARCHAR(50), @two NVARCHAR(50), @three NVARCHAR(50)

SELECT  cinfo.ID,
    cinfo.Nam,
    cinfo.INAM,
    cinfo.CA,
    cinfo.Form,
    cinfo.Std,
    cval.Prop,
    cval.Cons,
    sc.Accep

From dbo.Info AS cinfo
Inner JOIN dbo.values AS cval
    ON cinfo.ID = cval.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Sources AS sc
    ON (cval.sID = sc.sID AND sc.Accept = 'A')
IF @three IS NOT NULL{               **<---------------------**
LEFT JOIN dbo.Synonym AS synm
    ON cinfo.ID = synm.ID}

where (cinfo.NAM LIKE '%'+@one+'%' OR cinfo.CAS LIKE '%'+@two+'%' OR 
  synm.SynonymID LIKE '%'+@three+'%') AND
    (cval.PropID = '1' OR
    cval.PropID = '2' OR
    cval.PropID = '3' OR
    cval.PropID = '4' OR)
```

Comment: You cant do this in `TSQL`. However we can write the query to get results in both conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give that condition while joining itself.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search] 
@one NVARCHAR(50), @two NVARCHAR(50), @three NVARCHAR(50)

SELECT  cinfo.ID,
    cinfo.Nam,
    cinfo.INAM,
    cinfo.CA,
    cinfo.Form,
    cinfo.Std,
    cval.Prop,
    cval.Cons,
    sc.Accep

From dbo.Info AS cinfo
Inner JOIN dbo.values AS cval
    ON cinfo.ID = cval.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Sources AS sc
    ON (cval.sID = sc.sID AND sc.Accept = 'A')
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Synonym AS synm
    ON (cinfo.ID = synm.ID and @three is not null) **<---------------------**

where (cinfo.NAM LIKE '%'+@one+'%' OR cinfo.CAS LIKE '%'+@two+'%' OR 
  synm.SynonymID LIKE '%'+@three+'%') AND
    (cval.PropID = '1' OR
    cval.PropID = '2' OR
    cval.PropID = '3' OR
    cval.PropID = '4' OR)
```

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't you just use an `and` on the join? The join will be attempted but if @three is null then no joins to synonym would occur....  or do you really need to ignore the join for performance reasons? if so Dynamic SQL is the only way I could see to make it work...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search] 
@one NVARCHAR(50), @two NVARCHAR(50), @three NVARCHAR(50)

SELECT  cinfo.ID,
    cinfo.Nam,
    cinfo.INAM,
    cinfo.CA,
    cinfo.Form,
    cinfo.Std,
    cval.Prop,
    cval.Cons,
    sc.Accep

From dbo.Info AS cinfo
Inner JOIN dbo.values AS cval
    ON cinfo.ID = cval.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Sources AS sc
    ON (cval.sID = sc.sID AND sc.Accept = 'A')
LEFT JOIN dbo.Synonym AS synm
    ON cinfo.ID = synm.ID
   and @three IS NOT NULL               **<---------------------**

where (cinfo.NAM LIKE '%'+@one+'%' OR cinfo.CAS LIKE '%'+@two+'%' OR 
  synm.SynonymID LIKE '%'+@three+'%') AND
    (cval.PropID = '1' OR
    cval.PropID = '2' OR
    cval.PropID = '3' OR
    cval.PropID = '4' OR)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct syntax, but you could do achieve this in few ways, the dumbest way to do is add the Boolean check on the top.

```
IF @three IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
--FULL QUERY that JOIN dbo.Synonym 
END 

IF @Three IS NULL
BEGIN
--FULL QUERY that does not JOIN dbo.Synonym 
END
```

Or you could use `case..when` to control, it does the same thing as multiple `if`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by building dynamic query like following

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search] 
@one NVARCHAR(50), @two NVARCHAR(50), @three NVARCHAR(50)

DECLARE @query varchar(2000)=' SELECT  cinfo.ID,
    cinfo.Nam,
    cinfo.INAM,
    cinfo.CA,
    cinfo.Form,
    cinfo.Std,
    cval.Prop,
    cval.Cons,
    sc.Accep

From dbo.Info AS cinfo Inner JOIN dbo.values AS cval ON cinfo.ID = cval.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Sources AS sc ON (cval.sID = sc.sID AND sc.Accept = ''A'')'

IF @three IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   SET @query = @query + ' LEFT JOIN dbo.Synonym AS synm ON cinfo.ID = synm.ID '
END

SET @query = @query + 'where (cinfo.NAM LIKE ''%' + @one + '%'' OR cinfo.CAS LIKE ''%' + @two + '%'' OR 
  synm.SynonymID LIKE ''%' + @three + '%'') AND
    (cval.PropID = ''1'' OR
    cval.PropID = ''2'' OR
    cval.PropID = ''3'' OR
    cval.PropID = ''4'')'

EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: This has now exposed this procedure to sql injection. You need to parameterize that dynamic sql if this is the solution.

Comment: NO it is not!!! The parameters are inbound to the procedure but then you are building a string and executing it. This is a very common misunderstanding. But what happens if the value for one is something like "'x''; drop database master;--". This code has opened this procedure up to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search] 
@one NVARCHAR(50), @two NVARCHAR(50), @three NVARCHAR(50)

SELECT  cinfo.ID,
    cinfo.Nam,
    cinfo.INAM,
    cinfo.CA,
    cinfo.Form,
    cinfo.Std,
    cval.Prop,
    cval.Cons,
    sc.Accep

From dbo.Info AS cinfo
Inner JOIN dbo.values AS cval
    ON cinfo.ID = cval.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Sources AS sc
    ON (cval.sID = sc.sID AND sc.Accept = 'A')
LEFT JOIN dbo.Synonym AS synm
    ON (cinfo.ID = synm.ID AND @three IS NOT NULL)

where (cinfo.NAM LIKE '%'+@one+'%' OR cinfo.CAS LIKE '%'+@two+'%' OR 
  synm.SynonymID LIKE '%'+@three+'%') AND
    (cval.PropID = '1' OR
    cval.PropID = '2' OR
    cval.PropID = '3' OR
    cval.PropID = '4' OR)
```

Answer (score 0):

replace IF @three with this :

```
 LEFT JOIN (select * from dbo.Synonym  where @three IS NOT NULL) as synm ON cinfo.ID = synm.ID
```

and verify ALTER procedure syntax and LIKE syntax.

Answer (score -3):

```
You cannot use { for if condition just remove '{'

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search] 
@one NVARCHAR(50), @two NVARCHAR(50), @three NVARCHAR(50)

SELECT  cinfo.ID,
    cinfo.Nam,
    cinfo.INAM,
    cinfo.CA,
    cinfo.Form,
    cinfo.Std,
    cval.Prop,
    cval.Cons,
    sc.Accep

From dbo.Info AS cinfo
Inner JOIN dbo.values AS cval
    ON cinfo.ID = cval.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Sources AS sc
    ON (cval.sID = sc.sID AND sc.Accept = 'A')
**IF @three IS NOT NULL**           Remove this line
LEFT JOIN dbo.Synonym AS synm
    ON cinfo.ID = synm.ID}

where (cinfo.NAM LIKE '%'+@one+'%' OR cinfo.CAS LIKE '%'+@two+'%' OR 
  synm.SynonymID LIKE '%'+@three+'%') AND
    (cval.PropID = '1' OR
    cval.PropID = '2' OR
    cval.PropID = '3' OR
    cval.PropID = '4' OR)
```

Try to write
Like
 IF @three IS NOT NULL
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search] 
    @one NVARCHAR(50), @two NVARCHAR(50), @three NVARCHAR(50)

```
SELECT  cinfo.ID,
    cinfo.Nam,
    cinfo.INAM,
    cinfo.CA,
    cinfo.Form,
    cinfo.Std,
    cval.Prop,
    cval.Cons,
    sc.Accep

From dbo.Info AS cinfo
Inner JOIN dbo.values AS cval
    ON cinfo.ID = cval.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Sources AS sc
    ON (cval.sID = sc.sID AND sc.Accept = 'A')

where (cinfo.NAM LIKE '%'+@one+'%' OR cinfo.CAS LIKE '%'+@two+'%' OR 
  synm.SynonymID LIKE '%'+@three+'%') AND
    (cval.PropID = '1' OR
    cval.PropID = '2' OR
    cval.PropID = '3' OR
    cval.PropID = '4' OR)
```

end
else
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search] 
    @one NVARCHAR(50), @two NVARCHAR(50), @three NVARCHAR(50)

```
SELECT  cinfo.ID,
    cinfo.Nam,
    cinfo.INAM,
    cinfo.CA,
    cinfo.Form,
    cinfo.Std,
    cval.Prop,
    cval.Cons,
    sc.Accep

From dbo.Info AS cinfo
Inner JOIN dbo.values AS cval
    ON cinfo.ID = cval.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Sources AS sc
    ON (cval.sID = sc.sID AND sc.Accept = 'A')
LEFT JOIN dbo.Synonym AS synm
    ON cinfo.ID = synm.ID}

where (cinfo.NAM LIKE '%'+@one+'%' OR cinfo.CAS LIKE '%'+@two+'%' OR 
  synm.SynonymID LIKE '%'+@three+'%') AND
    (cval.PropID = '1' OR
    cval.PropID = '2' OR
    cval.PropID = '3' OR
    cval.PropID = '4' OR).. rest code
```

end

Comment: Still doesn't work. Says: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT' for the same line

Comment: The IF statement is used to control flow, you can't just throw it in the middle of a query like this.

Comment: You cannot write IF condition in middle of query like you are doing in current condition. IF State must contain a query. for example. IF condition then your statement

Comment: Your recent edits make even less sense. Are you suggesting they change the stored procedure every time just before executing it?

Comment: No I am suggesting that you have written IF condition at wrong place. You cannot write It inside a statement. You have to write any statement in IF condition